# reshape() not taking up the float data type, does it only work with int() type

Tags: python, reshape

```
import numpy as np import pandas as pd file = open("C:\Temp_Python\FF\FF_New.txt","r") data = file.readlines() f = [] index = [] for i in range(1,np.size(data)): t = data[i].split() index.append(int(t[0])) for j in range(1, 5): k = float(t[j]) f.append(k/100)

n = len(f) nm = n/4 print(nm)

f1 = np.reshape(f, [nm,4])
ff = pd.DataFrame(f1, index=index, columns= ['mkt','smb','hml','rf'])

print (index)
print (f)
```

this is output here;

```
f1 = np.reshape(f, [nm,4])
```

this line is creating trouble

```
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/ujjwa/data retrieve processing.py') 19.0 Traceback (most recent call last):

File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\users\ujjwa\data retrieve processing.py:18 f1 = np.reshape(f, [nm,4])

File <array_function internals>:200 in reshape

File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:298 in reshape return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)

File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:54 in _wrapfunc return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:43 in _wrapit result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: It kind of makes sense, since an array can't have a non-integer number of elements. What about just doing `nm = int(n/4)`? If `n` would even not be a multiple of 4, then that needs some thought to determine what you want your output array to look like.

Comment: I am a beginner, and this code is from the book Python for Finance by Yuxing Yan. Yes, nm = int(n/4); this was added by me just trying to take integers in the reshape()

Comment: I see. It could be that the book was written with Python 2 in mind. In Python 2, `n/4` would have been an int, but in Python 3 it's a float.

Comment: could you please correct the code

Comment: Either `nm = int(n/4)` or `nm = n//4` fixes this for Python 3.